# htaccess How to add a versioning number to css and js files

Tags: .htaccess

I need a simple htaccess rule to add a string to all css and js files.

everytime we update the software we need to make sure that people load the new js and css files and not use the cached ones...

I found some code where they strip out the version number.

```
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[0-9]{10}\.(css|js)$ $1.$2 [L] # Strip out the version number
```

but I would actually need the opposite.

at the moment a css file is like that in the page

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/forms.css" type="text/css">
```

I would like to accheive

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/forms.css?v=118" type="text/css">
```

same for JS

Your help is much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: why you want to do it with .htaccess?

Comment: You could add `v=<?= md5_file("http://path/to/your/css") ?>` in your template, and this way every time you changed the css or js file, new version will be applied automatically

Comment: What is the link that you want to place in your web pages?

Comment: there are about 50 different js and css files each included in static html pages, therefore I cannot add any php code to make a generic file name. also I would like to be able to increase the number only if a new version / software release is out. so that the regular browser caching functions work.